# Field Calculator: Split address into house number, street name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, address

I have an `ADDRESS` field in a table with values like:

- 1 MAIN ST
- 20 SIDE AVE W
- 300 JOHN DOE JR RD S

I want to use the field calculator to split the addresses and insert the parts into `HOUSE_NUMBER` and `STREET_NAME` fields. 
Example:

- `300` into `HOUSE_NUMBER`
- `JOHN DOE JR RD S` into `STREET_NAME`

I also want the tool to check if the value that will be put into `HOUSE_NUMBER` is a valid integer (and ignore it if it isn't).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This python script seems to do the trick. It allows the user to choose whether to return the **house number** or the **street name** to the field (by commenting-out the non-applicable `ReturnType` line).

```
def addressParser(inString):
    returnType = "House Number"
    #returnType = "Street Name"

    splitString = inString.split(' ',1)
    houseNumber = splitString[0]
    streetName = splitString[1]

    if returnType == "House Number":
        if houseNumber.isdigit():
            return houseNumber
        else:
            return
    if returnType == "Street Name":
        return streetName
    else:
        return
__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
addressParser(!ADDRESS!)
```

Sources:

- [A better way to parse an address?](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/163731#comment-575794)
- [Built-in Types: Split Function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: I have a related question here: [How to design configurable scripts for non-programmers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/111508/how-to-design-configurable-scripts-for-non-programmers)

Comment: I hinted some ideas over there.

Comment: streetName should be ' '.join(splitString[1:]) to create a string out of **every word but the first** otherwise the 3rd example would be just 'JOHN' rather than 'JOHN DOE JR RD S' or depending on your requirements ' '.join(splitString[1:]).title() to return 'John Doe Jr Rd S' might be suitable. Were you to run this in a python script rather than as field calculator expression you could update both values at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelStimson the code specifies that it is only splitting the string at the first space .split(' ', 1) so **the code will work as written**.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
def format_address(address_string):
    # Declare variables
    hn =""
    ha =""
  # Separate the address string into parts
    address_string = address_string.split()
  # Traverse through the address parts
    for add in address_string:
        if add.isnumeric():
            hn += add
        else:
            ha += add + " "
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
  # Does anything else need to be done
  # before returning the result?

  # Return the formatted string
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(hn,ha)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```