# Field calculator returning ERROR 000989?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I'm trying to split a field of street addresses (field name "PROP_STREE") so that it returns only the house number (so "123 Main St" would become "123").

Following the solution provided [Field Calculator: Split address into house number, street name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254169), I am using the following script:

```
def addressParser(inString):
  splitString = str(inString).split(' ')
  houseNumber = splitString[0]
  return houseNumber

PROP_NUM = addressParser(!PROP_STREE!)
```

But it keeps returning "Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 6)."

What mistake am I making in my code?

Here's what the Field Calculator window looks like, for reference.

[image]

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6.1.

Comment: And what it the datatype of the field `prop_num`?

Comment: It is a string. (I forgot to include that line of code-- just added it.)

Comment: Check code block option and call function from box below.

Comment: Adding to what FelixIP has said, maybe you can specify that `inString` is actually a string, such that `str(inString).split(' ')`

Comment: @FelixIP what does that mean? I tried putting the code in the Pre-Logic Script Code box and entered addressParser(PROP_NUM) in the PROP_NUM = box. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Daniel I changed it to splitString = str(inString.split(' ')). Now I get Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 6). I *think* line 6 is either addressParser(!PROP_STREE!) or addressParser(PROP_STREE), not sure if line numbers are inclusive or not.

Comment: Replace picture in your post with latest.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm

Comment: When you split, you get a list of two elements, if you write `str(inString.split(' '))` of course it will raise an error. Try it as I wrote it. In the midtime, let me check what you have written about `addressParser`

Comment: @Daniel oh of course, stupid of me, I didn't even notice-- I should have copy/pasted instead of typing. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @FelixIP I've updated my post to show what I am currently using!

Comment: Remove last 2 lines in codeblock. Replace line in a box below by current last line in codeblock.

Comment: @FelixIP Now it's giving me "Error executing function: The value type is incompatible with the field type. [PROP_NUM]". I've updated my post again. Sorry :( :(

Comment: Ok, so write `houseNumber = int(splitString[0])`, just to be sure how did you defined `PROP_NUM` as integer, float or string (when you created the filed value)?

Comment: It means that field NUM is numeric and you have house numbers like 24B. Create new field, make sure it is text. Can be done without block !stree!.split(" ")[0]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!!